# React router v6 history.listen

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In React Router v5 there was a listen mehtode on the history object.
With the method I wrote a usePathname hook to rerender a component on a path change.
In React Router v6, this method no longer exists. Is there an alternative for something like this? I would hate to use useLocation because it also renders if the state changes, which I don't need in this case.

The hook is used with v5.

```
import React from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router";

export function usePathname(): string {
  let [state, setState] = React.useState<string>(window.location.pathname);

  const history = useHistory();
  React.useLayoutEffect(
    () =>
      history.listen((locationListener) => setState(locationListener.pathname)),
    [history]
  );
  return state;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am using now this code

```
import { BrowserHistory } from "history";
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { UNSAFE_NavigationContext } from "react-router-dom";

export default function usePathname(): string {
  let [state, setState] = React.useState<string>(window.location.pathname);

  const navigation = useContext(UNSAFE_NavigationContext)
    .navigator as BrowserHistory;
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (navigation) {
      navigation.listen((locationListener) =>
        setState(locationListener.location.pathname)
      );
    }
  }, [navigation]);

  return state;
}
```

It seems to work fine

Comment: I haven't had time to dig into this, but the bit that says 'UNSAFE_' is making me wonder how safe this solution really is for production code?

Comment: This no longer works in React Router 6.4 with DataBrowserRouter.

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned above, [useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-location) can be used to perform side effects whenever the current location changes.

Here's a simple `typescript` implementation of my location change "listener" hook. Should help you get the result you're looking for

```
function useLocationEffect(callback: (location?: Location) => any) {
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    callback(location);
  }, [location, callback]);
}

// usage:
useLocationEffect((location: Location) => 
  console.log('changed to ' + location.pathname));
```

Comment: one thing missing from `useLocation` that `history.listen` provided was [`action`](https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/main/docs/api-reference.md#history.listen). That can be accessed with [`useNavigationType`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-navigation-type) now.

Comment: i have changed the `(location?: Location) => any` to `(location?: ReturnType<typeof useLocation> => void)` since the Location type doesn't match the useLocation return type.

Comment: useLocation has to be used inside a route component. Sometimes we want to have the code running in a parent component overseeing everything.

Comment: this simplistically only provides you "to" route, but not the route your are navigation from. This seems crucial for being able to intercept request from specific page to another to do something.

Answer (score 4):

I find using `useNavigate` and `useLocation` quite meaningless compared to `useHistory` in React Rrouter v5.

As a result of these changes, I made a thin custom hook to ease myself from any refactoring.

Just rename the import path to this hook and use the "old" api with v6. To answer or just give hints to your question - using this approach is should be easy to implement the `listen` function in the custom hook yourself.

```js
export function useHistory() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();

  const listen = ...; // implement the hook yourself

  return {
    push: navigate,
    go: navigate,
    goBack: () => navigate(-1),
    goForward: () => navigate(1),
    listen,
    location,
  };
}
```

Comment: I also created an adaptor for useHistory to reduce the amount of code changes in all the components. This allows us to centralize the new implementation. The changes in all the other components will be to import from the adaptor instead of the react-router lib.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use `const { pathname } = useLocation();`? It will indeed renders if the state changes but it shouldn't be a big deal in most scenarii.

If you REALLY want to avoid such behaviour, you could create a context of your own to hold the pathname:

```
// PathnameProvider.js

import React, { createContext, useContext } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router';

const PathnameContext = createContext();

const PathnameProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  return (
    <PathnameContext.Provider value={pathname}>
      {children}
    </PathnameContext.Provider>
  );
}

const usePathname = () => useContext(PathnameContext);

export { PathnameProvider as default, usePathname };
```

Then you can use `usePathname()` in any component down the tree. It will render only if the `pathname` actually changed.

Answer (score 0):

Given that @kryštof-Řeháček's recommendation (just above) is to implement your own `useListen` hook, but it might not be obvious how to do that, here's a version I've implemented for myself as a guide (nb: I havent't exhaustively unit tested this yet):

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router";

interface HistoryProps {
    index: number;
    isHistoricRoute: boolean;
    key: string;
    previousKey: string | null;
}

export const useHistory = (): HistoryProps => {
    
    const { key } = useLocation();
    
    const [history, setHistory] = useState<string[]>([]);
    const [currentKey, setCurrentKey] = useState<string | null>(null);
    const [previousKey, setPreviousKey] = useState<string | null>(null);

    const contemporaneousHistory = history.includes(key)
        ? history
        : [...history, key];
    const index = contemporaneousHistory.indexOf(key);
    const isHistoricRoute = index + 1 < contemporaneousHistory.length;
    const state = { index, isHistoricRoute, key, previousKey };

    if (history !== contemporaneousHistory) setHistory(contemporaneousHistory);

    if (key !== currentKey) {
        setPreviousKey(currentKey);
        setCurrentKey(key);
    }

    return state;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I now have just created a new routing library for react where this is possible.

https://github.com/fast-router/fast-router

Server-Side rendering is not supported. The rest should work fine. The library is mainly inspired by wouter -> https://github.com/molefrog/wouter

There are hooks for example usePathname which only cause a new render if the actual pathname changes (ignoring the hash and search)
It is possible to select just a single property of the history.state and don't get a new render if any other values inside the state changes.