# React Router v.6 usePrompt TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am basically trying to intercept route changes. Maybe something equivalent of vue's `beforeEach` in **React Router v6** could be useful as React Router v.6 does **not** include `usePrompt`.

BEFORE each route change I want to do some logic - the logic might need to interrupt or even change the end route based on the result.

I have searched around but I really can't find something that solves this specific problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `react-router`/`react-router-dom` doesn't have this functionality. Could you provide a [minimal and complete code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the Vue code, and your attempt at something similar in React we can help?

Comment: @DrewReese I cant provide an example. Basically I want to display a modal/alert when the user tries to leave a specific route. It seems it was possible in react-router v5 with Prompt/Blocker

Comment: I see. Yes, currently that functionality has been excluded from RRDv6 (*supposedly it will return, TBD*), but I imagine you could replicate something close to it with a [custom router & history object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70646548/8690857) to listen for route changes, specifically the POP action, possibly combined with listening for the [beforeunload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64967211/8690857) event.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Currently they have removed the `usePrompt` from the react-router v6.

I found a solution from [ui.dev](https://ui.dev/react-router-preventing-transitions) and added TypeScript support, and am now using that until the react-router will bring back the `usePrompt`/`useBlocker` hooks

```
import { History, Transition } from 'history';
import { useCallback, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { Navigator } from 'react-router';
import { UNSAFE_NavigationContext as NavigationContext } from "react-router-dom";

type ExtendNavigator = Navigator & Pick<History, "block">;
export function useBlocker(blocker: (tx: Transition) => void, when = true) {
    const { navigator } = useContext(NavigationContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!when) return;

        const unblock = (navigator as ExtendNavigator).block((tx) => {
            const autoUnblockingTx = {
                ...tx,
                retry() {
                    unblock();
                    tx.retry();
                },
            };

            blocker(autoUnblockingTx);
        });

        return unblock;
    }, [navigator, blocker, when]);
}

export default function usePrompt(message: string, when = true) {
    const blocker = useCallback((tx: Transition) => {
        if (window.confirm(message)) tx.retry();
    }, [message]);

    useBlocker(blocker, when);
}
```

This can then be used in any view/component where you would like a "A you sure you want to leave?"-message displayed when the condition is true.

```
usePrompt("Do you want to leave?", isFormDirty());
```

Comment: Hey bro, is there anyway to not using `any`? Cause my eslint rule (`no-explicit-any`).

Comment: @Tuan You can remove the as any casting, if you import the correct Navigator type. I didnt initially see that you need to import that type from react-router, but i just checked and that should work. I have updated my answer accordingly

Comment: I tried implementing this but Transition no longer exists on 'history'

Comment: @swedish_junior_dev Cant see anything about that mentioned in the [5.3 changelog for "history"](https://github.com/remix-run/history/releases) (I used 5.2 version of the npm package "history" and that worked fine. What version are you using?

Comment: @idkwhatsgoingon I had version 4.9.0. Updated to latest and the error is gone. Thx!

Answer (score 3):

Using the other solutions listed here against react-router v6.8.0, I got errors stating that `navigator.block` is undefined when I tried pass a `true` into the second argument of `usePrompt`

After a little digging on the react-router GitHub pages, I found the maintainer's [docs explaining why the changes happened](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/3a44ce30353f89d57386b75e90e05a79b18b2525/decisions/0001-use-blocker.md) but I also found this little [gem](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/0e4c524b329bf9641ccfc85da95bcde708bc56ca/examples/navigation-blocking/README.md) pushed in recently.

While there currently isn't a full-fledged feature in the library, the `unstable_useBlocker` func can get the job done.

Here's a rough example that worked for me:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { unstable_useBlocker } from 'react-router-dom';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [shouldBlockLeaving, setShouldBlockLeaving] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const blocker = unstable_useBlocker(shouldBlockLeaving);

  if (blocker.state === 'blocked') {
    if (window.confirm('You have unsaved changes, are you sure you want to leave?')) {
      blocker.proceed?.();
    } else {
      blocker.reset?.();
    }
  }

  // reset the blocker if the user cleans the form
  useEffect(() => {
    if (blocker.state === 'blocked' && !shouldBlockLeaving) {
      blocker.reset();
    }
  }, [blocker, shouldBlockLeaving]);

  return (<>
    ...
  </>)
}
```

**Note that this is an incomplete example** because I have nothing setting the `shouldBlockLeaving` state to `true`, but hopefully this is easy to extrapolate from.

Here's a more thorough [example on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/remix-run/react-router/tree/main/examples/navigation-blocking?file=src%2Fapp.tsx)

Comment: unstable_useBlocker doesn't handle browser triggered events anymore. Have you found any way to prevent refreshing or closing tab that doesn't use event `onbeforeunload` that is not implemented in all browser?

Comment: No, unfortunately, but from my testing the original code using <Prompt /> I was migrating from had this exact same limitation, so it wasn't really a loss of functionality for my case, just continuation of the same "good enough for now" solution.

There's a lot of chatter on the react-router GitHub page about this feature being re-added so I'm really hoping a future version addresses the problem you cited.

https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8139

Comment: This is pretty cool. I modified to `blocker.reset()` everytime when `shouldBlockLeaving` is `true` and stored the target location in `redux` from `blocker.location.pathname`. Created a custom confirm dialog and if the user confirmed, then navigated to the stored location.

Answer (score 0):

`useBlocker` hook has been reintroduced and deemed stable as of version [6.19](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#v6190).
Official docs [here](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-blocker).

Comment: That is true. However you are forced to use react-router's newer versions of routers if you want to use this. When wrapping your app in the previously standard <BrowserRouter>, you will get this error: `useBlocker must be used within a data router.  See https://reactrouter.com/routers/picking-a-router.`

Answer (score -1):

Yes `usePrompt` and `useBlock` has been removed, but you can achieve same thing using `history.block`, here is the working example for blocking navigation using `history.block` with custom modal in React Router Dom V5

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { UnregisterCallback } from "history";
...

type Prop = {
  verify?: {
    blockRoute?: (nextRoute: string) => boolean;
  }
};

...
// in the component where you want to show confirmation modal on any nav change

const history = useHistory();
const unblock = useRef<UnregisterCallback>();
const onConfirmExit = () => {
  /**
   * if user confirms to exit, we can allow the navigation
   */

  // Unblock the navigation.
  unblock?.current?.();
  // Proceed with the blocked navigation
  goBack();
};

useEffect(() => {
  /**
   * Block navigation and register a callback that
   * fires when a navigation attempt is blocked.
   */
  unblock.current = history.block(({ pathname: to }) => {
   /**
    * Simply allow the transition to pass immediately,
    * if user does not want to verify the navigate away action,
    * or if user is allowed to navigate to next route without blocking.
    */
   if (!verify || !verify.blockRoute?.(to)) return undefined;

   /**
    * Navigation was blocked! Let's show a confirmation dialog
    * so the user can decide if they actually want to navigate
    * away and discard changes they've made in the current page.
    */
   showConfirmationModal();
   // prevent navigation
   return false;
});

// just in case theres an unmount we can unblock if it exists
  return unblock.current;
}, [history]);
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is a JS example of the react-route-dom v6 usePrompt if you're not using TS.

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { UNSAFE_NavigationContext as NavigationContext } from 'react-router-dom';

export function useBlocker( blocker, when = true ) {
    const { navigator } = useContext( NavigationContext );

    useEffect( () => {
        if ( ! when ) return;

        const unblock = navigator.block( ( tx ) => {
            const autoUnblockingTx = {
                ...tx,
                retry() {
                    unblock();
                    tx.retry();
                },
            };

            blocker( autoUnblockingTx );
        } );

        return unblock;
    }, [ navigator, blocker, when ] );
}

export function usePrompt( message, when = true ) {
    const blocker = useCallback(
        ( tx ) => {
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-alert
            if ( window.confirm( message ) ) tx.retry();
        },
        [ message ]
    );

    useBlocker( blocker, when );
}
```

Then the implementation would be...

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    const formIsDirty = true; // Condition to trigger the prompt.
    usePrompt( 'Leave screen?', formIsDirty );
    return (
        <div>Hello world</div> 
    );
};
```

Here's the [article with the example](https://newdevzone.com/posts/in-react-router-v6-how-to-check-form-is-dirty-before-leaving-pageroute)

Comment: Sorry about that...was having trouble with the formatting. Supporting references added and link updated

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: navigator.block is not a function