# React Router v6 doesn't support usePrompt and useBlock anymore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I know that `react-router-dom` doesn't support `usePrompt` and `useBlock` anymore, well I have been trying to figure out if there are any ways to still use this function in `"react-router-dom": "^6.2.2"` version or making you're own `usePrompt` and `useBlock` that will do the same, I have done the  prompting function resolved but it only working if I close the `browser` or `refresh` it the below code works fine

```
  const closePrompt = (e: BeforeUnloadEvent) => {
    if (isFieldDisabled) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.returnValue = '';
    }
  };

  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', closePrompt);
```

but if the user changes the `route` to the existing app define `route` it will `redirect` it to that page without any `prompt` or `warning` to show.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71572678/react-router-v-6-useprompt-typescript It's Typescript but it should be trivial to strip out the typing bits.

Comment: thanks, mate I'm also a typescript guy finger cross hope the above solution will work!

Comment: Also, AFAIK the `usePrompt` and `useBlocker` code hasn't been completely deprecated. They just didn't include it with the v6 release and plan to bring it back in a future release, though it's unclear when. https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#prompt-is-not-currently-supported

Comment: yeah that i also read somewhere, thanks the above solution works.